# erlang n2o render get &lt;span id=&quot

Tags: web, erlang, n2o

I want to write web with n2o and rebar3.
but I get the page something wrong ,code is here.

index.erl

```
-module(index).
  -compile(export_all).
  -include_lib("n2o/include/wf.hrl").
  -include_lib("nitro/include/nitro.hrl").




  main() -> #dtl{file="prod",app=web, ext="dtl", bindings=[{body,body()} ]}.

  body() ->
      [ #span   { id=display },                #br{},
        #span   { body="Login: " },            #textbox{id=user,autofocus=true}, #br{},
        #span   { body="Join/Create Feed: " }, #textbox{id=pass},
        #button { id=loginButton, body="Login",postback=login,source=[user,pass]} ].
```

prod.dtl

```
<html >
<head>
  <title>{{title}}</title>
</head>
<body>
            {{body}}
</body>
</html>
```

I get the result :

```
<html >
<head>
  <title></title>
</head>
<body>
            &lt;span id=&quot;display&quot;&gt;&lt;/span&gt;&lt;br/&gt;&lt;span&gt;Login: &lt;/span&gt;&lt;input id=&quot;user&quot; type=&quot;text&quot; autofocus=&quot;true&quot;/&gt;&lt;br/&gt;&lt;span&gt;Join/Create Feed: &lt;/span&gt;&lt;input id=&quot;pass&quot; type=&quot;text&quot;/&gt;&lt;button id=&quot;loginButton&quot; type=&quot;button&quot;&gt;Login&lt;/button&gt;
</body>
</html>
```

how can i get get '<'  not '&lt'

Comment: Does changing `{{body}}` to `{{body | safe}}` in `prod.etl` work?

Comment: which version of DTL you're using?
N2O is supported up to 0.8. newer version up to you.

Comment: @Dogbert It's work....thanks

Comment: @Dogbert thanks, it's new to me :-)

Comment: @5HT I use rebar3_erlydtl_plugin .It use latest version of erlydtl .so...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`erlydtl` enabled auto escaping of the values inside `{{}}` in [this commit](https://github.com/erlydtl/erlydtl/commit/d840d7df196e301a77cc310b2ea878b5dda92fb8) (also see [`#80`](https://github.com/erlydtl/erlydtl/issues/80) and [`#120`](https://github.com/erlydtl/erlydtl/issues/120)). If you're using a version that includes this commit (from the page it looks like 0.9.0 or later), you'll have to manually mark the value as safe.

Instead of:

```
{{ body }}
```

do:

```
{{ body | safe }}
```

Note: You should be aware of the risks of marking an untrusted string as safe: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cross-site_scripting.